# C# Memory Editing Booleans

Tags: c#, memory, process, editing

I'm currently into messing around with memory in some games I play to see what I am able to do, I have a modified memory editing class to satisfy my needs however I am unable to edit or read boolean values which is causing me issue. The class helps me modify values of an external process through a hook.

Writing to a bool value is what I want to do most and this is what I have attempted but TBH I do not know what is wrong with it

```
public bool WriteBool(int Address, bool Value)
{
    byte[] bArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(Value);
    bool flag = Process_MemoryReaderWriter.WriteProcessMemory((IntPtr)this.Handle, (IntPtr)Address, bArray, 2, 0);
    return flag;

}
```

I also need to read some boolean values in which this is what I have attempted;

```
public bool ReadBool(int Address)
{
    IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    byte[] bArray = new byte[4];
    IntPtr intPtr1 = intPtr;
    Process_MemoryReaderWriter.ReadProcessMemory((IntPtr)this.Handle, (IntPtr)Address, bArray, 2, out intPtr1);
    int rBInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(bArray, 0);
    int num = rBInt;
    bool boolValue = num != 0;
    return boolValue;
}
```

I have determined that the booleans are the issue as everything else seems to work fine in which this is the last step where the program appears to fail.
As you can likely tell I don't really know what I am doing with this (Evidence it doesn't work) but any assistance would be helpful, with this in mind if possible please attempt to keep answers in a semi simple way.

I believe I have provided everything but if you need any more information please ask :)

Comment: How to structure a "boolean" value in memory depends on the platform and/or programming language in use. Usually they are stored as the integers 0 or 1, but they may differ in size, and could be 1, 2 or 4 bytes in size (even seen 8). Make sure you get the size right.

Comment: `BitConverter` is a helper class for serialisation, not a magic method that gives you the bytes your target wants. "Bool" is not a well-defined type, you need to know how true and false values are represented in the particular game (which depends on compiler, platform, "low-level" hacks...). `BitConverter.GetBytes(bool)` gives you a single byte that's either zero or one, which will pretty much *never* be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitConverter.GetBytes(bool)` returns a byte array of size 1, while it looks like WriteProcessMemory and ReadProcessMemory are expecting byte arrays of size 2 (Fourth parameter of each). Changing those to 1 should solve that issue. In addition, BitConverter also has a ToBoolean method, so for reading you could do something like:

```
public bool ReadBool(int Address)
{
    IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    byte[] bArray = new byte[1];
    Process_MemoryReaderWriter.ReadProcessMemory((IntPtr)this.Handle, (IntPtr)Address, bArray, 1, out intPtr);
    return BitConverter.ToBoolean(bArray, 0);
}
```

Just so you know, how other systems handle booleans isn't well defined, but you should be safe assuming that 0 == false at the very least. The byte size may be your main issue - some languages and systems use 4 bytes/float, others 1 so you might need to adjust your code as appropriate (For example, your ReadBool method works if the other process uses 4 byte bools).